# How to stretch full height div inside container the scroll?

Tags: html, css

I want `div.line` with border black like below code to have full height in container scroll.
When there is an element that is too long, for example, line number 4 the borders will be shortened, with no height until the end.
Is there a way for the elements inside the scroll container to always be the same height as the tallest element?
Thanks, everyone!

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.line {
  width: calc(100% / 4);
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0 16px;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
}

.line:nth-child(2) .item {
  height: 200px;
}

.line:nth-child(4) .item {
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="item">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="item">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="item">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="item">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, then

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Scroll flex</title>
    <style>
      .another-container {
        height: 300px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
      .container {
        display: flex;
      }
      .line {
        width: calc(100% / 4);
        border-left: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 0 16px;
      }
      .item {
        height: 100px;
        background: blue;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px;
      }
      .line:nth-child(2) .item {
        height: 200px;
      }
      .line:nth-child(4) .item {
        height: 600px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="another-container">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="line">
          <div class="item">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="line">
          <div class="item">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="line">
          <div class="item">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="line">
          <div class="item">4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Your solution does not work as intended because you set the height of your flex container explicitly, as @XiaoGuang pointed out. None of flex items could be greater than the container itself. So first step is to remove the height property and let the flex container to become as tall as the tallest flex item. After that, if you still need scrolling, just add another container for that.

Comment: It works fine, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use **grid** in this case instead of **flex**. Take a look at comments in code for more details.

```css
.container {
  display: grid; /* change to grid */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); /* create 4 columns */
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.line {
  width: calc(100% - 16px * 2); /* full width column */
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0 16px;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
}

.line:nth-child(2) .item {
  height: 200px;
}

.line:nth-child(4) .item {
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="item">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="item">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="item">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="item">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `.line` divs also contain an item, you need to make them flexboxs as well, and then make the item grow to the full height. Something like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.line {
  width: calc(100% / 4);
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  flex-grow: 1;     
}

.line:nth-child(2) .item {
  height: 200px;
}

.line:nth-child(4) .item {
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="item">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="item">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="item">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="item">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And that's basically it.